# What quality attribute would be favored using a rich search algorithm?

Tags: architecture, documentation, enterprise-architecture, quality-attributes

I'm working on an architecture document based on quality attributes. I'm trying to explain our search algorithm based on tags, historics and some bi information as a way of favouring a quality attribute.

I read some material about this ([*Software Architecture in Practice, Third Edition*](http://resources.sei.cmu.edu/library/asset-view.cfm?assetid=30264)) : usability is the closest I got (in the way of making it easy to search for something) but that is not quite right. I've read a [list of quality attributes in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_system_quality_attributes):  maybe correctness or relevance would apply? are those even formal quality attributes?

Comment: How would such "quality attributes" be used?  Would you base an acceptance criteria on them?  For that, they would have to be *measurable.*

Comment: Thanks for your reply. A user would be able to access a list of results that matches his needs (based on his info, historics, etc). A measure could be the how much  a user clics on a result, and how much success cases you have. It would be about getting the user what he needs/wants, sometimes doing a little guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a formal attribute, you'd better stick to [ISO/IEC 9126](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_9126) or its successor ISO/IEC 25010.

Following are "**functionality**" attributes:

- "correctness" corresponds to "accuracy". This means that it produces the correct results and with sufficient degree of precision.
- "relevance" seams to match "suitability".  This means that it provides the right functions for the user's task and objectives.

I understand you want to highlight how your algorithm is favoring/contributing to quality:

- not sure that "correctness" is a good match here, unless your algorithm has some feature that must be used to achieve correct results.
- "relevance" could be a good match as the algorithm will somehow make the searching more efficient, helping user to better achieve his/her goals.

"**Usability**" is a group of several attributes, that are about ease of use and attractivity. It's too general for a document about quality attributes.  The following would be more precise, and seem also to suit your needs:

- "operablity" is about facilitating the user to control the software while meeting user's expectations (e.g. better, more targeted search results ? thus avoiding lots of browsing across correct but less relevant results)
- "attractiveness" is about the emotions of the user.  For example, if this algorithm will make the user like your software more than comparable software using another search algorithm.

Comment: Much appreciated.